# Remote Blob Storage and MaxSiteCollection in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: site-collection, remote-blob-storage

looking online I found tons of material on Remote Blob Storage so I finally realise my content "redirect" on file system.

My question is very simple: in every tutorial I found the created DB has setted 1 as max number of site collection allowed... Is this a limitation? I Cannot have more than one SC if I use RBlob?

Thank you!